# Facebook deep linking for an iOS App when the app is not installed yet

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

When using Facebook deep linking into an iOS App, what happens after a user, that has not the app installed yet, clicks on a deep link (e.g., in a Facebook ad)? Will the deep link be followed after the app is installed and the user is authorized? Or are deep links only suitable for scenarios when the app is already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked it - when the app is not installed, clicking on a deep link, as expected, launches the iTunes store, the app is installed, the user logs in (with Facebook login in our case) and starts at the app's landing page - the deep link is not followed.